# How to keep same file name css files in asset

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

I bought many themes and put them under .//app/assets/

Then  include them by

```
*= require_tree ../lenord-single-page-theme/css
 *= require_tree ../ace-admin-theme/css
 *= require_self
 *= require_tree .
```

As you can see,

the two theme has many identical file names under their own folder,

If I just want to include both of them , and ignore the conflicts of their style.

What should I do ?

```
.//app/assets/ace-admin-theme/css/font-awesome.min.css
.//app/assets/lenord-single-page-theme/css/font-awesome.min.css
```

Comment: paste your files in app/assets and vendor/asset, when you have same file name. Include, require at once it will call both the files.